# Restarting a Twisted-python Reactor after an unsuccessful connection

Tags: python, client, twisted, reactor

I am writing a server with multiple clients. When a client starts, the server may not yet be working. So a `reactor.connectTCP` may fail (no receiving end). Currently I'm solving this by looping on a `reactor.run`, i.e.:

1. connect to server
2. reactor.run
3. if fails, repeat

I understand this is not the way to do it in twisted. How can I do it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try to reconnect within your `connectionLost` handler, for example:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory

class EchoClientFactory(ClientFactory):
    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        connector.connect()
```

There is also even a built-in [`ReconnectingClientFactory`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.ReconnectingClientFactory.html). See also: this blurb on [reconnection](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html#auto4).